# Free group of rank $2$ inside $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How to show that $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ contains a free group on two generators.

I do not how to approach this problem, How to pick the generators of the free group ?

Edit (following comments):
We know free product of cyclic group of order $2$ and cyclic group of order $3$ i.e. $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. The generators of that free group are \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} and \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

Now I know $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})=SL(2,\mathbb{Z})/\{+I, -I\}$.

Comment: Aren't free groups infinite in size?  You should explain more what your thought is.

Comment: @hardmath This product is the set of all words written with letters in the two groups, not ordered pairs of letters.  It will be infinite.

Comment: (Following your edit) If you have an isomorphism between your group and $PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$, why not just take the image of those two matrices under the isomorphism?  Your edit reduces the problem to a previously solved problem, which is the way of the mathematician!

Comment: @Aaron But I have only shown that, $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ contains a free group of rank $2$ not $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. Is it true that if I consider the equivalence class of the generators in $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, It generate a free group in $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: ${\rm PSL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$ is a quotient of ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$ by a subgroup of order $2$. Since free groups are torsion-free, if ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$ contains a free subgroup then so does ${\rm PSL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$.